# What is Bash source code that handles user input?

Tags: c, bash, input

I'm trying to write my own shell and I'm having a lot of problems implementing a noncanonical user input system. I've done countless Google searches, stack overflow searches, etc. and I've never found a solution that works quite like Bash's input system. I've used "tcsetattr" and "ncurses" and both methods had their issues. Instead of asking yet another question about how to make it work, I wanted to look at Bash's input code. However, I haven't been able to find the code that handles the keys that make noncanonical mode useful -- tab, up arrow, etc. Can anyone point me to the Bash code that handles input? I found "input.c" but that didn't look like what I referenced above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you are alluding to `readline` which is a separate library.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/readline/info

Comment: Readline is separate, but Bash and Readline are developed in tandem, and the Bash source tree contains readline (in `lib/readline`).

Comment: Wow, in all my research I never came across the `readline` library. Thanks for the replies.